# how to combine map and replicate on an array of integers

Tags: list, haskell

For a school exercise i need to generate a series of symbols with a given array of numbers. given is  `[3,3,2,1]` output `"+===+===+==+=+"`.
My approach would be to use `map` and `replicate` "=" on the array then `intercalate` "+" and finally `concat` the array to a single string.

My solution is something like this (while standing knee deep in errors)

```
printLine arr = map (replicate "=") arr >>> intercalate '*' >>> concat
```

what is the correct syntax? or shouldn't i use map at all?

Comment: N.B.: You mean "list" rather than "array".

Comment: Are sure you want to use the `(>>>)` operator, at this stage?

Comment: @Jubobs Though it is rather unusual, I don't see any harm.

Comment: @duplode Neither do I. I just find it weird that the OP would use such a relatively advanced operator at this stage of his/her Haskell learning.

Comment: well only the theory/implementation is advanced - the usage is trivial (and maybe the code is a bit easier to read than with `(.)` - so the teacher might have decided to introduce composition like this

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you are on the right track, you just mixed up the functions a bit:

- `replicate` will take a number `n` and repeat the second argument n-times into a list (so you just got the order wrong - you could use `flip` or an aux. function like I did bellow)
- you have to watch out if you want `Char` or `String` (`'='` VS `"="` for example) - read the type-definitions (try `:t intercalate` or [Hoogle](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.1.0/docs/Data-List.html#v:intercalate)) carefully and remember: `String ~ [Char]`!
- `intercalate` actually does the concatenation so you don't need concat at all

Here is a almost working version:

```
eqSigns :: Int -> String
eqSigns n = replicate n '='

mixIn :: [Int] -> String
mixIn = intercalate "+" . map eqSigns
```

try it and see if you get the missing parts in there ;)

---

here is the version with `flip` instead:

```
mixIn :: [Int] -> String
mixIn = intercalate "+" . map (flip replicate '=')
```

---

PS: are you coming from some ML/F# background?